# Can Canadian air travellers get home using public transit with new rules for on-arrival COVID tests? (Dec 2021)

Tags: air-travel, canada, covid-19

In response to the emerging [omicron variant](https://www.who.int/news/item/26-11-2021-classification-of-omicron-(b.1.1.529)-sars-cov-2-variant-of-concern) of COVID-19, Canada [recently announced](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/trudeau-omicron-more-to-do-1.6267817) that incoming air travellers will be required to take a COVID-19 test on arrival and then self-isolate until they receive results of the test.

The [guidance for self-isolation](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/isolation) suggests that use of public transportation is prohibited.

> Getting to your place of isolation (final destination)
>
> - Do not use public transportation (e.g. aircraft, bus, train, subway, taxi or ride-sharing service) to get to your place of isolation.

What does this mean for fully-vaccinated Canadian citizens who took public transportation (bus, train, or taxi) to the airport and don't have a car parked at the airport to drive home in? Does not having access to a private car mean that returning travellers will need to stay in a quarantine hotel?

Comment: This page states that use of public transport *is* allowed https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/isolation (confusingly, it seems to be under the ‘Driving to your place of quarantine’ section, within the ‘Getting to your place of quarantine’ guidance)

Comment: @Traveller please post as an answer.

Comment: @Traveller those are the rules for quarantine, but the new directive says that people must *isolate* until they have a test result. Isolation seems to have a different set of rules.

Comment: @Nic that page has rules for both quarantine and isolation. Isolation seems to be required only if you have symptoms or a positive test.

Comment: @jcaron The linked news article says "Incoming travellers will have to self-isolate until they receive results of the test."

Comment: @jcaron that makes sense to me. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This page states that use of public transport is allowed travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/isolation (confusingly, it seems to be under the ‘Driving to your place of quarantine’ section, within the ‘Getting to your place of quarantine’ guidance) –

The actual news release (linked in the warning at the top of the page on isolation) says “Fully vaccinated travellers will be required to quarantine while they await the results of their arrival test”. The choice of words (quarantine and isolation) for the two regimes is quite unfortunate since they are synonymous (and the two regimes quite close but not exactly).

(answer generated from comments)

Comment: I don't see such a section and the web page takes me [here](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid). The original question was over a year ago and things are very much different now.  Could you have a really old web page cached? I see such stuff in the wayback machine ca. September 2022.